# How Were the LCARS Panel Set Props Made in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, behind-the-scenes, lcars

Were the LCARS panels set props typically pre-designed transparency panels with dark glass and florescent lighting behind them? Or were the "buttons and layouts" added later with computers? I'm talking the TNG days.

Voyager and DS9, and some of the later Picard-era films I could see being computer-generated easily. Especially Nemesis and Insurrection.

Comment: The technology to superimpose images onto a screen shown in a video was either non-existent or very expensive during the time TNG was made.  If a shot shows *just* a computer screen and nothing else, then it could be done easily.  Otherwise, it would have been very hard to do without visible artifacts.

Comment: http://discuss.fleetworkshop.org/t/animated-back-lit-lcars-okudagram-translites/382 | http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Okudagram | https://www.trektoday.com/interviews/okuda_qa.shtml

Comment: Were computer graphics not so expensive for the time, Star Trek might have had many more holographic displays like the kind we saw a few times in TNG and never again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The panels were designed by Mike Okuda and printed on plastic film, which was then back-lighted. Later on they used actual flat-panel displays.

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Okudagram